# WP_Query how to add a thumbnail to the first post from the last 5 posts?

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails

I've a query like this:

```
<ul>
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '1', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); ?>

<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

<li>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) :  ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(230,163)); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php 
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

[image: Example: https://prnt.sc/kq4nha]

How can I show thumbnail the last added post?

Comment: As a note for the future, please add code and screenshots to the question itself. It is better to have all the information immediately available, additionally it makes it more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not specifying `order` and `orderby` parameters within your `WP_Query` query, the latest added post will be shown in the first place.

Having that in mind, you can do the following:

```
<ul>
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '1', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); ?>
    <?php $iterator = 0; ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && $iterator == 0 ) :  ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(230,163)); ?>
            <?php $done_last_post_thumbnail = true; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php $iterator++; ?>
    </li>
    <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
```

Of course, this will work only if the latest post has thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `current_post` property of `WP_Query`, it starts from 0. Exemplary usage:

```
if ( $custom_query->current_post == 0 && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
  //code
}
```